# how can I fix the application an error in the Heroku cloud?

Tags: django, heroku

I uploaded my website project on Heroku cloud a while ago and I needed to edit some stuff with the project and when I reupload the website again in the same app directory I get the message from Heroku that says **Application error** then I tried to create a new app directory in Heroku by command: `create heroku appname`
and when I upload my project doesn't work again with the different directory on Heroku so what is the step I missed here?
I followed up this lesson https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MoX36izzEWY&t=1707s step by step and I don't know what the step I missed or what is may the new in Heroku didn't exist in this tutorial?
- I did create a virtual environment
- I did create all files that Heroku needs like:

 ProcFile

 pipfile

 requirements.txt

and I installed everything as the tutorial said exactly: (gunicorn, django-heroku, whitenoise and so else)

last note:
I'm on Linux Ubuntu

Comment: `heroku logs -a <app_name>` use this in cli

Comment: it seems for me some errors have appeared but I don't know what error is occurring?

Comment: Add the logs in your post

Comment: thank you @Yashik for trying your help I found the error finally. I attached the error that I faced below

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
I had to install gunicorn into PipFile file side by side requirements.txt file
so, for the future coders, this is my mistake you have to install gunicorn into two files and they are: requirements.txt and PipFile
for Pipfile file you have to run the following command:

```
- $ pip3 install pipenv
- $ pipenv install gunicorn
```

Note that:
These commands run on the Linux system.